# Does the textbox that is generated when creating a detail view not count as a textbox?

Tags: vba, catia

My code searches for certain numbers in textboxes and replaces them. The code however does not change the number if it is in a textbox that is created from a detail view(see figure 1). Do these not count as textboxes?

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfVVZ.png)

```
Dim Totalsheets As Integer
Dim target_text As String
Dim FirstPage As Integer
Dim replace_text As String
Dim result As String

Dim n As Integer 'count No. of text frames changed
Dim i As Integer 'count views for the sheet
Dim x As Integer 'takes the value of the first page of the old config
Dim y As Integer 'takes the value of the total number of sheets of the old config
Dim z As Integer 'takes the value of the number that needs to be added to update the zoning
Dim a As String 'takes the value of the letter found in the zoning box
Dim b As Integer

n = 0
Set osheets = odoc.Sheets
Set osheets = osheets.Item("DRAFT") 'makes sure only sheet "DRAFT" is edited
Set oViews = osheets.Views

Totalsheets = Totalsheets1.Value 'draws value from the textbox
FirstPage = FirstPage1.Value 'draws value from the textbox

For i = 3 To oViews.Count 'scans through all views in sheet
    Set oView = oViews.Item(i)
    Set oTexts = oView.Texts
        For Each SrcText In oTexts 'scans through all text in view
            x = FirstPage
            y = Totalsheets
            b = x + y
            Do Until x = b + 1
                z = x + Totalsheets
                a = "A"
                Do Until a = "[" 'goes from A to Z
                    result = SrcText.Text
                    target_text = " " & x & a 'gets space in front and letter at back to ensure only zone box are updated
                    replace_text = " " & z & a
                        If InStr(result, target_text) Then
                            result = Replace(result, target_text, replace_text)
                            SrcText.Text = result
                            n = n + 1
                        End If
                    a = Chr(Asc(a) + 1)
                Loop
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the detail view identifier is a `DrawingText`, it does not belong to the `DrawingTexts`-collection.
You could access the `DrawingText` by searching in the view.
Better would be to rename the property of the view.

EDIT:
Example for using the (slower) selection:

```vb
Set oSel = oDoc.Selection   
oSel.Clear  
oSel.Add oView
oSel.Search "CATDrwSearch.DrwText,sel"
for i = 1 to oSel.Count2
   Set oDrwText = oSel.Item2(i).Value
   'do something with the text
next
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit my code in order to allow It to edit the detail view identifier? I am new to VBA and honestly not very sure how to incorporate your solution.

Comment: You could try these procedure: select the view -> search in the view -> loop through the selected elements
You can use the macro recorder for such a selection
(see also the (http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/interfaces/interface_Selection.htm#Search) documentation

Comment: I am sorry, i am a little confused. From my understanding(correct me if i am wrong) my code already searches through each individual view in the respective sheet. I understand the view identifier doesnt belong to the texts-collection that my code searches through but i am not sure what you mean by accessing the drawingtext of the view identifier by searching the view.

Comment: You are not using selection for your "search", you are looping through the object collections. This is usually the best way.
You can also use the selection (manually via Edit -> Search) to search for objects. But this is much slower.

Comment: What i am confused on is that your suggestion was to search inside the views, i am not sure what code to use to search for a text while in the view. Doesnt the code For each scrtext in otext do that alr?

Comment: Because the identifier of the detail view does not belong to the _drawingtexts-collection_, your _for each scrtext_ fails.

Comment: Ah i see. I am still not sure what the lines of code i need to use to access the detail identifier while in the view. I am not sure how to get access to the detail identifier's textbox in order to edit it.

Comment: Please have a look on my edited answer.